# Problems with String's replace() method

Tags: java, string

I am trying to replace parts of String starting with `$` (I manually use parameters in String) but for some reason it fails. Here's what I have:

```
 public void sendNotificationOfAcceptedMeeting(String candidateName, DateTime dateTime) {
        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String,String>();
        params.put("date", dateTime.toString(DATETIME_FORMAT));
        params.put("candidate", candidateName);
        sendEmailWithTemplate(TEMPLATE_ALL_ACCEPTED, params);
    }
```

then:

```
private void sendEmailWithTemplate(String templateName, Map<String, String> params) {
    EmailTemplate template = emailTemplateDao.getEmailTemplate(templateName);
    String subject = applyTemplateParameters(template.getSubject(), params);
    String body = applyTemplateParameters(template.getTetxBody(), params);
    sendEmail(subject, body);
}
```

and finally:

```
private String applyTemplateParameters(String templateText, Map<String, String> params) {
    String toReturn = templateText;
    if (params != null) {
        System.out.println("map size: " + params.size());
        for (Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("********************");
            System.out.println(toReturn + "   ***BEFORE");
            toReturn.replace("$" + entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            System.out.println("$" + entry.getKey() + "  ***KEY");
            System.out.println(entry.getValue() + " ***VALUE");
            System.out.println(toReturn + "   AFTER");
        }
    }
    return toReturn;
}
```

As you probably figured, the second method calls the third method with String that I want to modify and map of parameters and their values. Second method sets the vlue of `template` String to:

```
    The meeting request at $date with $candidate was accepted by all interviewers.
```

However the sysouts in third method print:

```
    map size: 2
********************
The meeting request at $date with $candidate was 
accepted by all interviewers.   ***BEFORE
$candidate  ***KEY
Acceeedsasd Stetfghfghasd ***VALUE
The meeting request at $date with $candidate was 
accepted by all interviewers.   AFTER
********************
The meeting request at $date with $candidate was 
accepted by all interviewers.   ***BEFORE
$date  ***KEY
27/12/2014 8:00 ***VALUE
The meeting request at $date with $candidate was 
accepted by all interviewers.   AFTER
```

which clearly shows that it doesn't replace parameters... I thought maybe `$` breaks it (regex) but `replace()`, unlike `replaceAll()` takes String - not regex. I'm out of ideas, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do this:

```
 toReturn = toReturn.replace("$" + entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
```

and then print the value of toReturn

Comment: :).. Atleast you got the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the "$" in your code with "\0024"

Like this:

toReturn = toReturn.replace("\0024" + entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());

Comment: As I said, $ was not a problem since replace takes String as input, not regex. Thanks for trying though :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the replace method returns a `String` and this wasn't being used. See below where I have put the result into `replacedText`.

```
String replacedText = toReturn.replace("$" + entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
System.out.println("$" + entry.getKey() + "  ***KEY");
System.out.println(entry.getValue() + " ***VALUE");
System.out.println(replacedText+ "   AFTER");
```

Answer (score 1):

String is immutable, cant be replaced,
just

```
toReturn = toReturn.replace("$...","")
```